# How to sort an array of objects by datetime in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

Given an array:

```
unsortedArray = [
  {'Email': 'jen@test.com', 'Created': '1/15/14 15:01'}, 
  {'Email': 'julia@test.com', 'Created': '1/16/14 18:21'}, 
  {'Email': 'andy@test.com', 'Created': '1/15/14 22:41'}, 
  {'Email': 'julia@test.com', 'Created': '1/16/14 18:20'}, 
  {'Email': 'victoria@test.com', 'Created': '1/16/14 23:05'}, 
  {'Email': 'lindsey@test.com', 'Created': '1/17/14 9:02'}, 
  {'Email': 'jim@test.com', 'Created': '1/17/14 11:28'}
]
```

How to sort this by 'Created' attribute, newest to oldest?

Comment: As usual, what have you tried?

Comment: @Julien this is not a helpful comment - if you don't have either the answer or a pertinent suggestion, then please refrain from chiming in.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the built-in `sorted` function, along with `datetime.strptime`

```
from datetime import datetime

sortedArray = sorted(
    unsortedArray,
    key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['Created'], '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), reverse=True
)
```